# Evaluating an Expression of Variables stored in object in R

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to compute an output over data tables based on the expression of variables stored in the object. Below is the sceneraio

```
expres = ('Intercept + `Driver Value`')

> expres
```

[1] "Intercept + `Driver Value`"

Now I want to use this object of variable expression on my data stored in data table named raw.
Without referencing, it would be like **raw[,.(Intercept[1] + `Driver Value`),]**

Any suggestions of how i can do this using referencing. Please let me know for any clarifications.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is `raw`?  Is it a `data.table` object?  Perhaps `raw[, eval(parse(text = expres))]`

Comment: Yes, raw is a data table object. And Intercept and Driver Value in the expression are the columns of the data table raw

Comment: Then the above code should work

Comment: Great. Will update once I try it. Thanks

Comment: Here is an example that I tried `raw <- data.table(Intercept = c(1, 3, 5), `Driver Value` = c(5, 3, 1))`  Note the Driver Value should be inside backquotes

Comment: Thanks. Worked straight. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

We can use the `eval(parse` route

```
raw[, eval(parse(text = expres))]
```

#### data

```
raw <- data.table(Intercept = c(1, 3, 5), `Driver Value` = c(5, 3, 1))
expres = ('Intercept + `Driver Value`')
```